# Stripe: Use Stripe Charge API but considering switching part of checkout flow to Stripe Checkout API?

Tags: stripe-payments

My entire site uses the Stripe Charge API and Custom Connect.  We also use the Charge API to allow customers to add a credit card and then use it later.
We were considering using Stripe's new Checkout API just for new cards and then continue using Charge API for purchases made with already stored cards. 
However, if we went with this approach and used the Checkout API for new cards,  would we then need to use the PaymentIntents API to be able to save that card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not need to use PaymentIntents to save the card, but you would need to use PaymentIntents to collect money with the new style PaymentMethod object created as the result of the new Checkout. For what it's worth, you can use older Card with the new PaymentIntents API by passing their ID in the `source` field when creating or confirming a PaymentIntent.